# Why does my newly created Ebean object have the wrong id?

Tags: java, orm, playframework, ebean

I create an object (the class Occupant does not define a constructor) and save it:

```
Occupant o = new Occupant();
o.setAProperty("value");
o.save();
```

After I save it, the object cannot be found with:

> Occupant.find.byId(o.getId())

However, I can find it as the only entry in:

> Occupant.find.all()

I am certain they are one in the same but they HAVE DIFFERENT IDs!

I am using oracle, and the Occupant class uses the same sequence generator that several other classes are using (and are immediately findable by id after save()).

> public class Occupant extends Model {
>
> @Id
>     @Constraints.Max(10)
>     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_favorite_seq")
>     @Constraints.Required
>     private String id;

As a side note, I checked the db directly and o.getId() is about -30 from my_favorite_seq.nextval while the id in Occupant.find.all() is -1 from my_favorite_seq.nextval.

Ebean must be pooling sequence values and then getting confused about when to use them? Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by turning on some logging ala http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/logging

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle sometimes people use a trigger on insert to fetch the nextval from the sequence and insert it in as the ID.

This was that.

Dropped trigger, life back to normal.